# How to prove these facts about integers using this definition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

A subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, the set of real numbers, is said to be inductive if $1 \in A$ and if the statement $x \in A$ implies the statement $x+1 \in A$.

The $Z_+$ of positive integers is defined to be the intersection of all the inductive subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

And, the set $Z$ of integers is defined to be the set consisting of all positive integers (i.e. all elements of $Z_+$), the number $0$, and the negatives of the elements of $Z_+$.

Using these definitions, how to prove that

(1) the sum, difference, and product of two integers is an integer, but the quotient of two integers need not be an integer?

(2) given an integer $n$, there is no integer $a$ such that $n < a< n+1$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

For (1) use the fact that $a+b=c$ is the same as using $a\in Z_+$ means $a+1\in Z_+$, $b$ times thus $c$ is also an integer. And for $a-b=c$ rearrange into $a=b + c$ so the same argument holds. Now for the quotient you only need a single counter example. Choose any odd $n$ and divide it by $2$ and see what happens.

For (2) consider an $a\in Z_+$ then assume that $n\in Z_+$. Now say that $n<a<n+1$. Now $Z_+$ is inductive (prove this) and we need to prove $a-1\in Z_+$ to prove $a\in Z_+$. So the argument should show that at the end of this logical chain there is no such $a-n\in Z_+$ because it would be smaller or larger than 1 by a non integer amount.

Comment: (1) requires a bit more work than that, since $b$ need not be positive.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott In that case $--b$ can be defined or shown to be $b$ so it follows from the first?

Answer (score 0):

I guess Saaqib Mahmood was reading "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres when he asked these questions.

---

(2)

(a). On p.32 in "Topology 2nd Edition", Munkres proved that $1$ is the smallest element of $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$.

(b). On p.35 in "Topology 2nd Edition", there is an exercise(exercise 5.(d)) in which we need to prove that $c - d \in \mathbb{Z}$ if $c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $n$ be any integer.
Assume that there is an integer $a$ such that $n < a < n + 1$.
Then $0 < a - n < 1$.

By (b), $a - n \in \mathbb{Z} := \mathbb{Z}_{+} \cup \{0\} \cup (-\mathbb{Z}_{+})$.

If $a - n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, then $a - n \geq 1$ by (a). This is a contradiction.
So, $a - n \notin \mathbb{Z}_{+}$.

$0 < a - n$, so $a-n\neq 0$, so $a - n \notin \{0\}$.

So, $a -n \in -\mathbb{Z}_{+}$.
So, $n-a \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$.
So, $n-a \geq 1$ by (a).
So, $n-a >0$.
So, $a-n < 0$. This is a contradiction.

So, there is no integer $a$ such that $n < a < n+1$.

---

(1)

(c). On p.35 in "Topology 2nd Edition", there is an exercise(exercises 5.(d) and 5.(e)) in which we need to prove that $c + d, c - d, c \cdot d \in \mathbb{Z}$ if $c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $c:=1$ and $d:=1+1$.
Then, $c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $1 > 0$, $1 + 1 > 0 + 1 = 1 > 0$.
So, $1 + 1 > 0$.
So, $(1+1)^{-1} > 0$.
So, $c/d = c \cdot (1/d) = 1/d > 0$.
So, $(1+1)^{-1} \cdot 1 < (1+1)^{-1} \cdot (1+1) = 1$.
So, $c/d < 1$.

So, $0 < c/d < 1$.

By (2), $c/d \notin \mathbb{Z}$.